# How to takeaway seconds to time.strftime in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to use this time format that I have:

```
time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
```

So, if I were to print it, it would look like this:

```
2015_11_20_15_28_03
```

And I was wondering how I could takeaway seconds from it. I've only had luck with finding how to add hours and minutes, which don't work for seconds.

Comment: It sounds like you figured out your own problem, but you A) still might want to fix your question to make it clearer you mean subtracting seconds versus not showing seconds B) Show what you had working with hours/minutes that didn't work with seconds and then C) answer your own question to show how you got it to work.

Answer (score 6):

Simply exclude the `%S`, which represents seconds, if you don't want it.

```
time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I worded it really badly, which was my fault. I meant subtracting actual seconds from the time. As in, the time now is 13:15 and 12 seconds. I want to print 13:15 and 11 seconds. I've found out how to do it now though, I just put some decimal points in the format I currently have.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to do time calculations on a time format, you should be doing calculations on a time object. You could turn this string into a time object, do the calculation, then turn it back into a string, but it'd be better to leave the formatting for last.